# Reverse Owl Carousel on last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

By default owl carousel display slides in order like this, for example if I have 3 slides:

```
[1] [2] [3] [1] [2] [3] [1] [2] [3] ...
```

I want to achieve this:

```
[1] [2] [3] [2] [1] [2] [3] [2] [1] ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can imitate a reversal by cloning of items.

1. Clone items that are in the middle:
   `[1] [2] [3] [4]` -> `[1] [2] [3] [4] [3] [2]`.
2. Start [Owl Carousel 2](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-options.html) in `loop` mode.

Please check the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/pEZpEP

```js
var classCarousel = '.owl-carousel';
var selectCarousel = $(classCarousel);

/* 1. */
var i;
for (i = selectCarousel.children().length - 1; i > 1; i--) {
  selectCarousel.children(':nth-of-type(' + i + ')').clone().appendTo(classCarousel);
}

/* 2. */
selectCarousel.owlCarousel({
  autoplay: true,
  dots: false,
  items: 1,
  loop: true,
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.2.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">

<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/936/fff/?text=1" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/693/fff/?text=2" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/369/fff/?text=3" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/f63/fff/?text=4" alt=""></div>
</div>
    
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2//2.0.0-beta.2.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Yes I was looking for something like this.